# mongodb - get difference of zero if it should be zero for sorting in the query

Tags: mongodb

Usually zeros and field not existing can be handled on the client side. In my situation, I need it to use in the sort function of the mongodb query.

Here is my query:

```
            {
            "$group": {
              "_id": "null",      
              "upCount": { "$sum": "$up" },
              "downCount": { "$sum": "$down" } 
            },
           },
           { 
            $project: {
              difference: { $subtract: ["$upCount", "$downCount"] },
              // Add other keys in here as necessary
              upCount: 1,
              downCount: 1,
            }
          },
```

and in the sort

```
.sort({ 'commentVotes.difference': -1 }
```

This works perfectly when there are values for upCount and downCount.

The problem is: I will have cases where commentVotes.difference can be negative when there are more downvotes than upvotes. In such cases, the comments with zero votes are sorted last even after the negative ones because they do not return a difference of zero.

In short, how can the below line return a value of `0` when `"$sum": "$up"` and `"$sum": "$down"` dont have any values?

```
difference: { $subtract: ["$upCount", "$downCount"] },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$ifNull`, if the values are null (Don't have nay value), then use `0`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      difference: {
        $subtract: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$upCount",
              0
            ]
          },
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$downCount",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playgroud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JHDyAgNPIaN)

Comment: ah nice answer. I did come across ifNull and I should have used it.